# How can the sizes and rotations of text of a pandas scatter matrix be set?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scatter

I'm creating a big scatter matrix and want to change the text such that it is neat, aligned, doesn't overlap etc. To do this I want to explore reducing the font size and changing the text rotation (and anything else reasonable). How could I do this?

[image]

[image]

The following attempt has not worked:

```
scatter_matrix = pd.scatter_matrix(
    data,
    figsize  = [15, 15],
    marker   = ".",
    s        = 0.2,
    diagonal = "kde"
)
plt.xticks(fontsize = 2, rotation = -90)
plt.yticks(fontsize = 2)
plt.savefig("scatter_matrix.jpg", dpi = 700)
```

Comment: Looks like you already know how to change font size and text rotation. What's your actual question?

Comment: "has not worked" is not a sufficient problem description. What is the outcome, in how far is it not what you want? Be precise about your requirement ("I want a neat plot" is impossible to give an answer to).

Comment: @Goyo I tried to illustrate that the font size and text rotation was not changing by posting images of the results. The solution by piRSquared indicates that one needs to iterate over all of the plots changing their characteristics individually.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I tried to illustrate that the font size and text rotation was not changing buy posting images. I'll try to be clearer in future.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The reason it isn't working is that `scatter_matrix` is a numpy array of axes.  `plt` can't work on all those axes at once.  You need to iterate through them and do your adjustments.

```
scatter_matrix = pd.scatter_matrix(
    data,
    figsize  = [15, 15],
    marker   = ".",
    s        = 0.2,
    diagonal = "kde"
)

for ax in scatter_matrix.ravel():
    ax.set_xlabel(ax.get_xlabel(), fontsize = 20, rotation = 90)
    ax.set_ylabel(ax.get_ylabel(), fontsize = 20, rotation = 0)
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks for your clear answer. I hadn't realised that iteration was necessary and the `ravel` method is great.

Comment: @BlandCorporation you are welcome

Comment: The documentation for `ravel` is here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ravel.html